# Center non text within a table

Tags: asp.net, css, dotnetnuke, ascx

I am trying to figure out a way to center a "rating" within a table, I can figure out how to align text and images but i can not figure out how to align this rating, since its technically not text or an image.

the code looks like below

```
<td align="center" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #444444;" 
    valign="top">
    <cc2:DnnRating ID="ProductReviewAverageOverallRatingDnnRating" 
                    runat="server" ReadOnly="true"
                    Value='<%# Eval("ProductReviewAverageOverallRatingDnnRating_Value") %>' 
                    Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ProductReviewAverageOverallRatingDnnRating_Visible")) %>'>
    </cc2:DnnRating>
```

...
    
I would assume that it would go somewhere within the first line. As you can see the text-align is there and vertical-align etc... but it does not work.

```
<td align="center" 
    style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #444444;" 
    valign="top">
```

I need direction on what to do or how this can be accomplished,

Thank You in advance
this part if from an inspect

```
td valign="top" align="center" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #444444;"><div id="dnn_ctr416_ViewRevindexStorefrontProductShowcase_ctl00_ProductShowcaseDnnRotator_i2_ProductReviewAverageOverallRatingDnnRating" class="RadRating RadRating_Default" style="width: 104px; height: 24px;"><ul class="rrtItem"><li class="rrtSelected"></li><li class="rrtSelected"></li><li class="rrtSelected"></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a href="#" title="5"><span></span>
```

Comment: Try using margin:0 auto; in the style rule?

Comment: i am not 100% sure on your question, but i think this is what you are asking for. '<ul class="rrtItem">
        <li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>1</span></a></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>2</span></a></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>3</span></a></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>4</span></a></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>5</span></a></li>
       </ul>'

Comment: sorry it did not format it correct

Comment: i posted the inspect in the orig. question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried style="margin:0px auto;"?  I can't tell what the rendered HTML would be from the control.  Thanks!

Comment: when i try to use style="margin:0px auto;" it breaks the whole site

Comment: '<ul class="rrtItem"><li class="rrtSelected"></li><li class="rrtSelected"></li><li class="rrtSelected"></li><li class="rrtSelected">' this part is what you are talking about in the html?

Comment: Yes.  You will need to have a specified width set on the ul tag/classname.  Within that same tag/css class you would add the margin:0px auto;

.rrtItem {
 width: ##px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

Comment: <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #444444;" valign="top">
                <ul class="rrtItem" style="width: 100px;margin:0px auto;"> <li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>1</span></a></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>2</span></a></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>3</span></a></li><li class="rrtSelected"><a title="5" href="#"><span>4</span></a></li></ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Comment: this last part worked great, i now am able to see how this works, by adding the class this defines where the output should be :) thank you very much for your assistance

Comment: this is that part that worked for me :)

 <ul class="rrtItem" style="width: 100px;margin:0px auto;">

Answer (score 0):

I assume the list in the comment is the html generated from the cc2:dnnRating control. Lists get rendered with some padding to make room for the bullets. Is this what is messing up your alignment? You can get rid of both bullets and paddings using styles, as described here:
[W3Schools CSS Navbar](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)

Comment: padding may be a part of it but bullets are not, I have read through the link you posted and don't really think this applies here in this case

Comment: I think you are correct about the list in the comments is being generated from the cc2:dnnRating

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping it in a SPAN or a DIV and then use 'margin:0px auto;'

Answer (score 0):

Try these style changes

Add following css

```
ul.rrtItem
{
   width:80%;
}
```

In `td` add `padding-left 19%` and `padding-right 19%`